# Laravel many to many loading related models with count

Tags: php, laravel-4, many-to-many, eloquent, pivot-table

I am trying to link 4 tables and also add a custom field calculated by counting the ids of some related tables using laravel.
I have this in SQL which does what I want, but I think it can be made more efficient:

```
DB::select('SELECT 
                        posts.*,
                          users.id AS users_id, users.email,users.username,
                          GROUP_CONCAT(tags.tag ORDER BY posts_tags.id) AS tags,
                          COUNT(DISTINCT comments.id) AS NumComments, 
                          COUNT(DISTINCT vote.id) AS NumVotes
                        FROM 
                          posts    
                          LEFT JOIN comments ON comments.posts_id = posts.id
                          LEFT JOIN users ON users.id = posts.author_id
                          LEFT JOIN vote  ON vote.posts_id = posts.id
                          LEFT JOIN posts_tags  ON posts_tags.posts_id = posts.id
                          LEFT JOIN tags  ON tags.id = posts_tags.tags_id

                        GROUP BY 
                          posts.id, 
                          posts.post_title');
```

I tried to implement it using eloquent by doing this:

```
$trending=Posts::with(array('comments' => function($query)
                {
                    $query->select(DB::raw('COUNT(DISTINCT comments.id) AS NumComments'));

                },'user','vote','tags'))->get();
```

However the NumComments value is not showing up in the query results.
Any clue how else to go about it?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can't do that using `with`, because it executes separate query.

What you need is simple `join`. Just translate the query you have to something like:

```
Posts::join('comments as c', 'posts.id', '=', 'c.id')
    ->selectRaw('posts.*, count(distinct c.id) as numComments')
    ->groupBy('posts.id', 'posts.post_title')
    ->with('user', 'vote', 'tags')
    ->get();
```

then each post in the collection will have count attribute:

```
$post->numComments;
```

---

### However you can make it easier with relations like below:

Though first solution is better in terms of performance (might not be noticeable unless you have big data)

```
// helper relation
public function commentsCount()
{
    return $this->hasOne('Comment')->selectRaw('posts_id, count(*) as aggregate')->groupBy('posts_id');
}

// accessor for convenience
public function getCommentsCountAttribute()
{
    // if relation not loaded already, let's load it now
    if ( ! array_key_exists('commentsCount', $this->relations)) $this->load('commentsCount');

    return $this->getRelation('commentsCount')->aggregate;
}
```

This will allow you to do this:

```
$posts = Posts::with('commentsCount', 'tags', ....)->get();
// then each post:
$post->commentsCount;
```

And for many to many relations:

```
public function tagsCount()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('Tag')->selectRaw('count(tags.id) as aggregate')->groupBy('pivot_posts_id');
}

public function getTagsCountAttribute()
{
    if ( ! array_key_exists('tagsCount', $this->relations)) $this->load('tagsCount');

    $related = $this->getRelation('tagsCount')->first();

    return ($related) ? $related->aggregate : 0;
}
```

More examples like this can be found here http://softonsofa.com/tweaking-eloquent-relations-how-to-get-hasmany-relation-count-efficiently/

Comment: Thank you, I wound up doing something similar to get the results I wanted. Less clean, but worked fine for what i needed.

Comment: Aint the link wrong ? this is the one that should be referenced http://softonsofa.com/tweaking-eloquent-relations-how-to-get-hasmany-relation-count-efficiently/ it is your own page damn you :P

Comment: @JarekTkaczyk This works perfectly for first degree relationships. I tried tweaking it and use it on : `Country > City > Person`, where I would want to count all people in a `Country`. instead of `hasOne`, I am using `hasManyThrough('Person','City')`. All is fine, except `people_count` (the relation) comes with all fields from the `Person` table, not just `city_id` and `aggregate`. How can I avoid polluting the results with unnecessary data ?

Comment: @AbderrahmaneTAHRIJOUTI Show me a paste of your code and its result pls.

Comment: @JarekTkaczyk http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29261913/count-and-sum-a-second-degree-relation-in-laravel-5

Answer (score 0):

as of laravel 5.3 you can do this

```
withCount('comments','tags');
```

and call it like this

```
$post->comments_count;
```

[laravel 5.3 added withCount](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships)