# Laravel eloquent count hasMany relations

Tags: laravel, model, eloquent

I have a database, with 2 main tables :

```
etablissement
site
```

So i created 2 models

**Site.php**

```
class Site extends Eloquent {
    public function etablissement() {
        return $this ->hasOne('Etablissement','code_etablissement','code_site');
    }
}
```

**Etablissement.php**

```
class Etablissement extends Eloquent {
    public function sites() {
        return $this ->hasMany('Site', 'code_etablissement', 'code_etablissement');
    }

    public function etablissementCountSites() {
        return $this->sites->count();
    }
}
```

As you can see, here's how my relations are working :

**"etablissement" can have multiples "site"**

**"site" can only have one "etablissement"**

"etablissement" **primary key** is "code_etablissement"

"site" **primary key** is "code_site", having **the foreign key** "code_etablissement" referencing to "etablissement.code_etablissement"

I want to count how many "site" an "etablissement" have. This is why i created the function "etablissementCountSites()" above.
So, in my controller, i am making this :
**HomeController.php**

```
private function gen_accueil()
    {
        $etablissement = Etablissement::select('code_etablissement','nom')->from('etablissement')->orderBy('code_etablissement')->get();
        $sitesCounter = Etablissement::with('etablissementCountSites')->get();

        return View::make('accueil',  array('which_actif' => 0, 'etablissement' => $etablissement, 'compteurSites' => $sitesCounter));
    }
```

And in my blade page i have this :
**accueil_blade.php**

```
@for ($i = 0 ; $i < count($etablissement); $i ++)
            <a class="btn popoverOption" data-content="Nombre de sites total : {{$compteurSites[$i]}}" rel="popover" data-original-title="{{$etablissement[$i]->code_etablissement}}" data-placement="bottom" href="{{ URL::to('dashboard_etablissement/' . $etablissement[$i]->code_etablissement)}}">{{$etablissement[$i]->nom}}</a><br>
@endfor
```

Everything should work... But i got this as error :

**Table 'MYNET.etablissements' doesn't exist (SQL: select * from `etablissements`)**

I searched all over the code, i don't have any "etablissement**S**" word anywhere. But i had previously.
Is it possible that Laravel didn't refreshed this ?

Comment: Set `$table` and `$primaryKey` properties on your models accordingly. Change wrong relation `hasOne` to `belongsTo`.

Comment: I added the protected variables primary key and table.
and changed the relation to belongsTo

I now have this :
Call to a member function addEagerConstraints() on a non-object

Comment: Because you're trying to load relation `with(etablissementCountSites)` while this is simple method, not a relation. Read this, there's the answeer for you http://stackoverflow.com/a/25665268/784588

Comment: I used your 1:N way to do.
But we're going for the same issue no ?
i mean, everything seems alright, but how can i access the data for each "etablissement" ?
You wrote :// then each post:
$post->commentsCount;
That would be the equivalent for : 
$sitesCounter->siteCount;
But i can't access it in a blade page right ?

Comment: Not at all. If you follow the instructions in that answer then you're good to go. You need `sitestCount()` relation and `getSitestCountAttribute()` accessor, that's all.

Answer (score 0):

Laravel when actually assume the table name if one is provided, and it does so by making plural of the model name. To your model, add:

```
class Establissment extends Eloquent 
{
    protected $table = 'thetablenamehere';
}
```

Also, naming a table as plural is considered best practise.