# Count then Sum a second degree relation in laravel 5

Tags: php, eloquent, laravel-5

While referring to @JarekTkaczyk's [method](http://softonsofa.com/tweaking-eloquent-relations-how-to-get-hasmany-relation-count-efficiently/), I am trying to count all people in a country.

1. A City `hasMany` People
2. A Country `hasMany` Cities

using `hasManyThrough` in Country, like so :

```
public function peopleCount(){
    return $this->hasManyThrough('App\Person', 'App\City')
        ->selectRaw('city_id, count(*) as count')
        ->groupBy('city_id');
}
```

I can access the count of People in each city. Yet it returns more than just the two fields `city_id` and `count` ! the count is correct, but the rest of the data is not something I'd want there. Here is an example : http://i.imgur.com/o1fyvEy.png

1. How do I make the query drop the other columns ?
2. How do I go further than counting students in each class, by summing all the counts into one value ?

Edit : more details on point two :

When I use the new made relation `peopleCount` to count all people in a country, it does so by counting all people in cities that belong to the country, thus returning a collection of counts that corresponds to each city, example in the following :

```
>>> $country = App\Country::with('peopleCount')->find(1)
=> <App\Country> {
       id: "1",
       peopleCount: <Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection> [
           <App\Person> {
               city_id: "1",
               count: "3", //<-------
               id: "1",
               country_id: "1"
           },
           <App\Person> {
               city_id: "2",
               count: "5", //<-------
               id: "4",
               country_id: "1"
           },
           <App\Person> {
               city_id: "3",
               count: "8", //<-------
               id: "9",
               country_id: "1"
           }
       ]
   }
```

To get the sum of counts I do it PHP side rather than database side like so : `$country->peopleCount->sum('count')`

So I would rather do it all inside the query than doing it php-side.

Comment: 1. You can't, because the relation adds select. Eloquent needs a bugfix ;) 2. I don't understand what you mean - show example

Comment: As for 1.  I already made a PR https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/8170. 2 I just noticed what you meant :) You have `city_id` in the group by clause, while you need `country_id` there, that's all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as per @Jarek Tkaczyk's response all i had to do was to `country_id` in the groupby clause