# Counting a many to many relationship?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent, laravel-5

I have a many to many relationship between users and images.

User Model

```
public function image()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('\App\Image');
}
```

Image Model

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('\App\User');
}
```

Tables

users

```
id | name
```

images

```
id | url
```

image_user

```
id | image_id | user_id
```

When a user 'favourites' an image, it's stored in the pivot table.

```
id | image_id | user_id
 1      1          1
 2      2          1
 3      1          2
```

I need a count of each images favourites.

I try something like:

```
 Image::with('user')->find(1)->count();
```

But this counts the number of users, not the number of favourites.

Ideally I would like to return all of the image data along with a count of the user data - how can I do this?

Comment: $module =Image::with('user')->get();  $module->user->count();

Comment: $module=Image::with('user')->get(); $module->count();

Comment: Thanks @kamlesh.bar but I was looking to do it all in the same query?

Comment: You should be able to chain it.

Comment: Image::with('user')->find(1)->user()->count();

Comment: Thanks @MrShibby but it does not answer my question, I still wish to return all of the image data along with a count

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this:

```
$image = Image::with('user')->find(1) // Get the image with user eager loading
$image->name; // Access any attribute
$image->users->count(); // Get the user count
```

You can even add a few lines in your Image model to create a "custom" attribute:

```
public function getFavoritesAttribute()
{
    return count($this->users);
}
```

And then use it like this:

```
$image->favourites;
```

There is a more detailed solution here:
[Laravel many to many loading related models with count](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25662854/laravel-many-to-many-loading-related-models-with-count)

EDIT: You can now use the withCount() method, that will count the number of related model without actually loading them.

In your case it will look like this:

```
$image = Image::withCount('user')->find(1);
$image->user_count
```

For more details: https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-relationships#counting-related-models

Comment: Thanks, so as a accessor the count will come out every time eloquent is called? Is this not wasteful?

Comment: The count is simply the php function. It does not perform a sql query every time.

Comment: So every time I call the model will the php do a count? This is what I mean by wasteful - I do not need a count on all() for example.