# Laravel Relationship 3 Models

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, eloquent-relationship

i have 3 models User, Campus, UserStatus. Structure is like this:

```
Campus
 - id
 - name
User
 - id
 - name
UserStatus
 - id
 - admission_date
 - current_status
 - user_id
 - campus_id
```

I would like to know how many users in a particular campus.. This is what i have done so far.

User.php

```
public function UserStatus()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Models\UserStatus' , 'user_id');
    }
```

Campus.php

```
public function UserStatus()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\UserStatus');
    }
```

UserStatus.php

```
public function User()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'user_id');
    }
public function Campus()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Campus', 'campus_id');
    }
```

what would be the relation for campus with user?

Comment: I know this doesn't really answer your question, but just curious: why have both User and UserStatus table? It looks like they all relate to a single user so couldn't it all go on the User table?

Comment: Im just showing relevant information here.. These tables have so much other columns in them.. I had to separate them due to some other relationships. in short it was kind of a requirement at the time.

Comment: So to clarify, User belongs to one Campus, and Campus has many Users correct?

Comment: yes thats correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead i used a function:

```
public function User()
    {
        $users = \App\User::whereHas('UserStatus', function($q){
            $q->where('campus_id', $this->id);
        });
        return $users;
    }
```

worked for me.. I was hoping there was a better way of establishing a relationship instead. but for now its working. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use "has-many-through" relationship.

Please check following URL.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through

Comment: The document suggests
`
countries
    id - integer
    name - string

users
    id - integer
    country_id - integer
    name - string

posts
    id - integer
    user_id - integer
    title - string
`
where as i dont have relation column on my second model.. both keys are in one model

Comment: you can use only UserStatus::where('campus_id', $particular_campus_id)->count();

Comment: so there is no way to access $campus->user->count();?

Comment: I think to it is no need to use relationship. Why? UserStatus has user_id and campus_id both. So you can get count in that table.

Answer (score 0):

You can use belongsToMany 
I think that you have the same problem like this and he solve this using belongsToMany and "with" in the query with eloquent  [Stack overflow - Counting a many to many relationship](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30507849/counting-a-many-to-many-relationship)

Comment: That is not resolved as well.. I also want to return all the users for a particular campus.. as i would need other information from these too.

Comment: i think that you can query UserStatus::where('campus_id',$campusId)->get(); and then you can loop through each row with (each) and then use the model to get the name of the user and store in a collection or array

Comment: i want to know which laravel version  are you using first.

Comment: I'm using laravel 5.8